Should we have a Featured Tag Wiki of the Month™?
Over the past few months, RE has accumulated a lot of quality content in the tag wikis due to the efforts of many our community members. There have been previous discussions on how to effectively bring out the wikis to the users of the site. With that in mind, I want to suggest an idea that will bring more attention to them.
Featured Tag Wiki of the Month™
As you might have noticed, there is a community bulletin that pops up from time to time on the site home page having links to meta posts, events notifications, or official SE announcements. We could highlight the good tag wikis by featuring/pinning them to the community bulletin for a period of a month.
The wikis suggested by users would be voted on by the community and/or evaluated by the Moderator Team (if needed). This would be done on a meta thread. We could try this out for a period of six months initially.
So, would you like to see this happen? Do you think this is needed?
Are there any changes you would like to suggest?

I can't decide whether there is a need for it. a single Tag might mean a complex topic that the visitor is unaware of... I 'feel' that some visitors are just following some activity, and ignoring the other, as reverse engineering requires a lot of practical experience IMO.
